# Color matching script that works well

Tags: php, mysql, scripting, colors, matching

Are there any scripts available for purchase, or free that can be used to match images based on the color chosen that works as good (or close) to the one found here: http://www.ideeinc.com/products/piximilar/ (not willing to pay millions of dollars)

- does not have to be multi color searching, one is good enough. (like googles color search). I have tried using the RGB distance formula but it brings up poor results

Comment: Use Google Scholar Search to find academic papers about identifying and matching colors in images. Implement one of those algorithms. That's what companies like Piximilar do.

Comment: I really do not have time to research and compile a script. I want to know if there are any premade that are available for purchase or are open to the public...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything ready to use. Off the top of my head I'd suggest to create a coarse 3d histogram of the HSL values of each image (say, 8 bins hor H, 4 for S and L), scale the histogram so that the sum of all cells is 1, then run a suitable pairwise metric (convolution, MSE) on all the histograms.
By applying some heuristics and clever indexing you can also avoid the O(N^2) complexity.